# gulp building css in dependency to folder

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

Is it possible to build an css file in dependency to my Theme folder? The problem is i have several themes in there with the same setup gulp should take Theme.scss and build an css file into Theme, Theme1 and so on.

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('Css/Clients/**/theme.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compact'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
    }))
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass', 'php'], function () {
    gulp.watch('Css/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
})
```

[image]

Edit:

im tryed the solution below the problem i get looks like this :

[image]

but i need just the theme.css in theme folder ander theme1.css in theme1 folder and so on! any suggestions ?

```
 gulp.task('sass', function () {
    var folders = getFolders(scriptsPath);

    var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
        return gulp.src(path.join(scriptsPath, folder, '/**/*.scss'))
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compact'}))
        // concat into foldername.js
        .pipe(concat(folder + '.css'))
        // write to output
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsPath))
        // write to output again
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsPath));
    });


   return merge(tasks);
    console.log(folders);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify multiple destinations like this:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('Css/Clients/**/theme.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compact'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/Theme'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/Theme1'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
    }))
});
```

Comment: so the result would be app/Theme1/Theme1.css? cause is exactly what i need just one file per folder

Answer (score 0):

Got it thanks guys!

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
var folders = getFolders(scriptsPath);

var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
    return gulp.src(path.join(scriptsPath, folder, '/**/*.scss'))
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compact'}))
    // concat into foldername
    .pipe(concat(folder + '.css'))
    // write to output
    .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsPath+folder))
});
```

});